# repeat array in arbitary length

Tags: python, numpy, repeat

Is it possible to create an array that looks like

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1
```

having the following array in the beginning

```
4, 3, 5, 2
```

without using loops in Python/Numpy?

**EDIT:**

This is just an example and the information (4,3,5,2) may have any length or numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> lengths = np.array([4, 3, 5, 2])
>>> np.concatenate(map(np.arange, lengths))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1])
```

Of course, this is cheating, because `map` is a loop in disguise. There's no NumPy idiom to do this any more directly, AFAIK.

The above creates `len(lengths)` temporaries. An alternative that does not construct these temporaries is to use `fromiter` and an adapted version of @jonrsharpe's answer:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, imap
>>> np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(imap(xrange, lengths)), dtype=int,
...             count=np.sum(lengths))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1])
```

Somewhat surprisingly, the `fromiter` idiom is faster, and it *gets faster if you don't compute the count first*:

```
>>> lengths = np.arange(30)
>>> %timeit np.concatenate(map(np.arange, lengths))
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.8 µs per loop
>>> %timeit np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(imap(xrange, lengths)), dtype=int, count=np.sum(lengths))
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.3 µs per loop
>>> %timeit np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(imap(xrange, lengths)), dtype=int)
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.8 µs per loop
```

(Timings of NumPy 1.8.1 and Python 2.7.6 on an x86-64 running Linux.)

Comment: @larsmans - any reason to use `map` and not the (to my mind) simpler `np.concatenate([np.arange(k) for k in lengths])` ?

Comment: @mtrw: because loops are not allowed :) Also I honestly like the brevity of `map`. But in Python 3, I would use the comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without writing `for` or `while`, but I assure you there's a loop under there somewhere!

```
>>> from itertools import chain, imap
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(imap(xrange, (4, 3, 5, 2))))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
```

[Powered by `itertools`.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Comment: Interesting solution, but I'm looking for pure numpy solution!

Comment: @Sebastian that was probably information worth putting in the question.

Comment: why did you ask for a python/numpy solution if you only want numpy?

Comment: sorry, maybe 'pure' is the wrong word here, but something with numpy functions...

Comment: +1 for suggesting an idiom that also works with NumPy, with one small change (see my, updated, answer).

Comment: @larsmans very neat, although if anything it seems slower than just passing my `list` straight to a new `np.array`!